# Use Java 8 streams to transform a Map with nulls

Tags: java, java-stream

I am dealing with a `Map<String,String>` that has `null` entries in the key and/or value:

```
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("SomE", "GreETing");
headers.put("HELLO", null);
headers.put(null, "WOrLd");

headers.keySet().stream().forEach(k -> System.out.println(k + " => " + copy.get(k)));
```

I get the following output:

```
SomE => GreETing
HELLO => null
null => WOrLd
```

I need to transform the map, so all the non-null values are converted to lowercase, like so:

```
some => greeting
hello => null
null => world
```

I am trying to use Java 8 streams API, but the following code is throwing `NullPointerException`:

```
Map<String,String> copy
    = headers.entrySet()
             .stream()
             .collect(
                 Collectors.toMap(
                     it -> it.getKey() != null ? it.getKey().toLowerCase() : null,
                     it -> it.getValue() != null ? it.getValue().toLowerCase() : null));

copy.keySet().stream().forEach(k -> System.out.println(k + " => " + copy.get(k)));
```

If I comment out the last two map entries, the program executes, so there must be an issue with how `Collectors.toMap` works when keys or values are null. How do I use the streams API to work around this?

Comment: maybe use optional: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html

Comment: toMap method throws that NPE for you have a null value, thanks @dkatzel

Comment: Actually `key` can be null. `value` can't be null

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is `toMap()` invokes the underlying Map implementation being built's `merge()` function which does not allow values to be null

from the javadoc for [`Map#merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) (emphasis mine)

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value or is associated with null, associates it with the **given non-null** value. Otherwise, replaces the associated value with the results of the given remapping function, or removes if the result is null.

So using `Collectors.toMap()` will not work.

You can do this without stream just fine:

```
Map<String,String> copy = new HashMap<>();

for(Entry<String, String> entry : headers.entrySet()){
    copy.put(entry.getKey() !=null ? entry.getKey().toLowerCase() : null, 
             entry.getValue() !=null ? entry.getValue().toLowerCase() : null
            );
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Use Collect:

```
final Function<String, String> fn= str -> str == null ? null : str.toLowerCase();
Map<String, String> copy = headers.entrySet().stream()
   .collect(HashMap::new,
            (m, e) -> m.put(fn.apply(e.getKey()), fn.apply(e.getValue())), 
            Map::putAll);
```

Or with [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common)

```
Map<String, String> copy = Stream.of(headers)
   .collect(HashMap::new, 
     (m, e) -> m.put(N.toLowerCase(e.getKey()), N.toLowerCase(e.getValue())));
```

updated on 2/4, Or:

```
Map<String, String> copy = EntryStream.of(headers)
   .toMap(entry -> N.toLowerCase(entry.getKey()), entry -> N.toLowerCase(entry.getValue()));
```

Comment: This is a good answer too. I am happy to get 3 working pieces of code. Now I need to work on understanding streams and lambdas better and these answers will help!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `Collectors.toMap()` without getting a NPE since you have a `null` `value` present in your `map`, as explained by @dkatzel already, but I still wanted to use `Stream API`;

```
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("good", "AsDf");
headers.put("SomE", "GreETing");
headers.put("HELLO", null);
headers.put(null, "WOrLd");

new HashSet<>(headers.entrySet()).stream()
    .peek(entry -> entry.setValue(Objects.isNull(entry.getValue()) ? null : entry.getValue().toLowerCase()))
    .filter(entry -> !Objects.isNull(entry.getKey()) && !entry.getKey().equals(entry.getKey().toLowerCase()))
    .forEach(entry -> {
        headers.put(entry.getKey().toLowerCase(), entry.getValue());
        headers.remove(entry.getKey());
    });

System.out.println(headers);
```

Prints out;

```
{null=world, some=greeting, hello=null, good=asdf}
```

Comment: I am interested in this example but I could not get the code to print anything. Can you elaborate or give me a working code snippet?

Comment: @WebUser it does not return anything, it directly modifies the original `headers` map you have, try to check its entries after you run this code!

Comment: Thanks! I would have voted for your answer if it had come in first. I am happy with the answer from @dkatzel and I don't want to revoke my best answer vote now. I did upvote yours and I hope others do too.

Comment: Terribly unmaintainable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have complicated checks and still want to use Collectors.toMap() without nulls

```
// convert data to a final key, value pairs using Pair.of(key, value)
.map(data -> {
    SomeKey key = makeKey(data.getKey());
    SomeVal val = makeValue(data.getValue());
    
    // validate and return 
    if(key.foo != null && val.bar != null) {
        return Pair.of(key.foo, val.bar);
    }
    return null;
})
.filter(Objects::nonNull)   // remove the ones that don't satisy criteria
.collect(Collectors.toMap(pair -> pair.getLeft(), pair -> pair.getRight(),  // then collect final key/value data without NPE checks
    (left, right) -> {
        left.merge(right); // can return null
        return left;
    }
)));
```